# undefined reference to boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to compile a program using `cmake`, and am seeing the following linker error:

> /home/quant/bin/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_log_setup.so:
>   undefined reference to
>   `boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(wchar_t const*, wchar_t
>   const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
>   std::allocator<char> >&, std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, __mbstate_t>
>   const&)' /home/quant/bin/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_log.so:
>   undefined reference to`
>   boost::filesystem::path_traits::dispatch(boost::filesystem::directory_entry
>   const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string,
>   std::allocator >&)'

The linker command that `ninja` generated looks like this:

> g++   -pthread -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK
>   utility/test/CMakeFiles/utilityTest.dir/loadCSVTests.cpp.o
>   utility/test/CMakeFiles/utilityTest.dir/main.cpp.o
>   utility/test/CMakeFiles/utilityTest.dir/randomDeviceTests.cpp.o  -o
>   utility/test/utilityTest  -rdynamic
>   /home/quant/bin/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread.so
>   /home/quant/bin/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_program_options.so
>   /home/quant/bin/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_serialization.so
>   /home/quant/bin/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework.so
>   /home/quant/bin/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_system.so
>   /home/quant/bin/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_log.so
>   /home/quant/bin/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_log_setup.so
>   /home/quant/bin/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.so
>   utility/lib/libutilityLib.a utility/testLib/libutilityTestLib.a
>   utility/lib/libutilityLib.a
>   /home/quant/bin/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread.so
>   /home/quant/bin/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_program_options.so
>   /home/quant/bin/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_serialization.so
>   /home/quant/bin/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework.so
>   /home/quant/bin/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_system.so
>   /home/quant/bin/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_log.so
>   /home/quant/bin/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_log_setup.so
>   /home/quant/bin/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.so
>   -Wl,-rpath,/home/quant/bin/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib

As you can see, I am linking against `boost_filesystem` and `boost_system`, so it's not the same problem as referenced on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972314/c-boostfilesystem-undefined-reference-to-boostfilesystem3pathroot-nam) (and the many others like it).

I am using `boost 1.61`, which I compiled with `gcc 5.3` (the same compiler as the one I'm compiling my program with).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, this could be because of a new ABI which is introduced from gcc 5.1.

https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/issues/4203

I fixed mine by adding "add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)" to CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Thank you so much! This absolutely helped!